# Laravel Validation - Using wildcard (*) in the error message

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

```
'attributes' => [
    'product_rate_.*.*' => 'Product .*. / .*.',
],
```

What i try to do is using wildcard(*) as variable in error message.

It shows like

> Product . * . / . * . area is required.

I want to see a message like that.

> Product 1 / 2 area is required.

How can i assign the * characters to variables and using them like @index1 and @index2 ?